# Opening a OFT file using Office JS

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to open a OFT file in Outlook add-ins using Office js.

I want to use the OFT template and create a new email. Currently I am converting all the content in OFT to HTML and pass it as a parameter to displayNewMessageForm.

Is there any way we can directly open a OFT file and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not a supported feature. Your method of using displayNewMessageForm is the recommended method.

We track feature suggestions through our User-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Hi Team, Thanks for the response